# Adding file extensions to files without them in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, command, file-extension

I am trying to add file extensions to a large number of files located in a series of folders and subfolders in Windows. For some reason, these files do not have a file extension on them and I need them to have the extension .ddd so I can convert them to PDFs using a separate program.

```
cd R:\PRODUCTION\92 
ren *. *.ddd
```

Note that this command does indeed work but only on folders that actually contain the files I need, and no subfolders. What could I add or change to hit all files in all subfolders? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following command. If it looks like it will do the correct rename, remove the `ECHO` from the REN command line.

```
CD /D R:\PRODUCTION\92
FOR /F "delims=" %f IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D "*."') DO (ECHO REN "%~f" "%~nf.ddd")
```

In a .bat file script, double the percent character on the variable.

```
CD /D R:\PRODUCTION\92
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D "*."') DO (ECHO REN "%%~f" "%%~nf.ddd")
```